# Macro to list all worksheets in a folder and subfolder

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to write some code that will dig in to each folder and subfolder in a directory to list the names of the worksheets in my workbooks. After much time and help from the posts on this forum, I have gotten this far but still do not have a working macro. I'm sure it's obvious, and I apologize for the gore, but does anyone have any idea why it is not working? Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Sub marines()
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String
    Dim OutputRow
    OutputRow = 2
    HostFolder = "G:\EP\Projects\"
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
End Sub


Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    Dim Workbook As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim HostFolder
    Dim OutputRow
       OutputRow = 2
       FileType = "*.xls*"
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next
    For Each Workbook In Folder.SubFolders
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & OutputRow).Activate
        OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
        Curr_File = Dir(HostFolder & FileType)
        Do Until Curr_File = ""
        For wb = wb.Open(HostFolder & Curr_File, False, True)
                ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & OutputRow) =     ThisWorkbook.Name
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & OutputRow).ClearContents
            OutputRow = OutputRow + 1

        Set Each ws In wb.Sheets
                ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & OutputRow) = ws.Name
                ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & OutputRow).ClearContents
                OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
            Next ws
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: There are many already working examples on how to do this on the web.  Just plugging in your title into google gave me quite a few.

Comment: What's not working? Do you get an error? Does it just run without displaying any results in your worksheet? If there's an error, does it give you the option of "Debug", and if so what line of code does it highlight?

Comment: Also, what is "Set Each ws In wb.Sheets"? Try Googling "For... Each in VBA"...

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime so I'll skip that part.

Simple solution: A module to withdraw all the workbooks in a folder and subfolders recursively and add them to a collection:

```
Public Sub ExtractAllWorkbooks(ByVal Addr As String, ByRef coll As Collection)
    DoEvents
    Dim objFSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim objFile As File, objFolder As Folder, objSubFolder As Folder

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Addr)

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If Right(objFile.Name, 5) = ".xlsx" And Left(objFile.Name, 1) <> "~" Then
            Call addStringToCollection(objFile.Path, coll)
        End If
    Next

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Call ExtractAllWorkbooks(objSubFolder.Path, coll)
    Next
End Function


Public Sub addStringToCollection(stringToAdd As String, coll As Collection)
    Dim st As String
    For i = 1 To coll.Count
        st = coll.Item(i)
        If st = stringToAdd Then Exit Sub
    Next
coll.Add stringToAdd
End Sub
```

With that, you just need to run in your main module:

```
dim Coll as New Collection
Const Addr As String = "G:\EP\Projects\"
Call ExtractAllWorkbooks(Addr, Coll)
```

Now you should have all the workbooks listed in the collection Coll. Just got to open them up and withdraw the worksheets' names elsewhere. Something like this should do the trick, assuming you are exporting the results to the worksheet wsRef:

```
dim wb as Workbook, ws as Worksheet
i = 2
For each st in coll
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(st)
    For Each ws in wb.Worksheets
        wsRef.Cells(i, 1) = wb.Name
        wsRef.Cells(i, 2) = ws.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next
```